# How do I censor after 5 years on SAS?

Tags: sas

How do I censor data points after 10 years? Some people experience a lot of events after 10 years, which messes up the data. So I only want to focus on the events during the first 10 years.

This is my fine and gray model:

```
proc phreg data=WORK.data plots(overlay=row )=cif ;
    class Ratio / param=glm;
    model TimeOutcome*Outcome(0)=Ratio / eventcode=1 rl;
    strata Ratio;
run;
```

Here is my marginal means model:

```
proc phreg data=work.data plots(overlay=row)=mcf covs(aggregate);
    class Ratio / param=glm;
    model Stop * Recur(0) = Ratio/entry = Start ;
    strata Ratio;
    id = id;
    hazardratio 'Hazard Ratio Statement 1' Ratio;
run;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would pre-process your data to account for this.
Check if the time variable is greater than 5, and if so, set it to 5 and censored. IF/THEN statements work well.

```
data data2;
set data;

if timeOutcome > 5 then do;
   timeOutcome=5; *sets time to 5;
    Outcome=0; *sets to censored;
end; 

run;
```

Then use data2 in your further data analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. But I wanted to double check.